# HTMLWorker itextSharp image src

Tags: c#, image, itext

I am trying to use HTMLWorker using the following:

```
  public static string toWorks(string s)
        {

            string fontpath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/");
            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontpath + "ARIALUNI.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            var f = new Font(bf, 10, Font.NORMAL);

            //     var p = new Paragraph { Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT, Font = f };
            var styles = new StyleSheet();
            styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.SPAN, HtmlTags.FONTSIZE, "10");
            styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.ENCODING, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);

            using (var sr = new StringReader(s))
            {
                List<IElement> list = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sr, styles);
                //  var elements = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sr, styles);
                foreach (var e in list)
                {
                    list.Add(e);
                }
                return list.ToString();
            }
            return null;

        }
```

It converts:

```
src="/Content/UserFiles/635380078478327671/Images/test.png
```

To:

```
C:\Content\UserFiles\635380078478327671\Images\test.png
```

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please compare the following two examples:

- [HtmlMovies1](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=55)
- [HtmlMovies2](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=56)

If you use the first example to render an HTML file with images, you probably won't succeed. The second example introduces an `ImageProvider` implementation.

In the `getImage()` method of the `ImageProvider` interface, you get information about the path to an image. It is up to you to interpret this path. For instance: if the path is `/Content/UserFiles/635380078478327671/Images/test.png`, you can create an `Image` object by loading the bytes from that path, possibly after applying some minor changes to the path.

If you don't create an `ImageProvider` class, iText will do a single guess to find the path. In your case, that guess is wrong.

You can find the C# equivalent of the examples here: http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C09

Comment: Bruno, I checked HtmlMovies2 could not find the reference for     Utility class (Utility.ResourcePosters,), where can I find it. Thanks

Comment: That's easy: http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Utility.cs

Comment: Thanks a million, you have been very helpful.  I wish to find a book about itextsharp and MVC with examples.

Comment: Writing about about iText and templates is on my TODO list after I've finished writing "The ABC of PDF": https://leanpub.com/u/itextsoftware

Comment: Looking forward, itextsharp is very useful tool.  Thank you.